flutter issue: the operand cant be null, so the condition is always true
I am facing an issue with code to integrate google maps into my app.
void _addMarker(LatLng pos) {
  var _origin;
  if (_origin == null || (_origin != null && _destination != null)) {
    setState( () {
      _origin = Marker(
        markerId: const markerId('origin'),
        infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'origin'),
        icon: 
            BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
        position: pos,);
    });
  } else {}

I can get issue at _origin == null. It says the operand cant be null. Please help me with this issue.

I think you should declare _origin as a class-level variable, and you can declare it like , Marker? _origin;
and the function can be like that :
Marker? _origin;

void _addMarker(LatLng pos) {
if (_origin == null) {
setState(() {
  _origin = Marker(
    markerId: const MarkerId('origin'),
    infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'origin'),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
    position: pos,
  );
});
} else {}
}


var _origin;

You are checking the value of that variable, which of course is null.
And dart analyzer is warning you, that variable can't be null but it's currently null which leading to make that condition always true.
To FIX
You have two options

assign a value to that variable before checking


doesn't make sense to check a variable while you are sure it has a
value


Remove it from that condition


Since you are sure it's null now, so what's the purpose of checking.

I suggest the second option.
btw, I'm keep thinking you are intending to check the value of another variable which has the same name of _origin. just recheck.
